# Set plugin's property on the command line in maven 2

Tags: java, maven-2, command-line

In maven 2.x, how would one set a plugin's property on the command line instead of in the <configuration> of that plugin in the pom or in settings.xml?

For example, if I was using `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`([seen here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html)) how can I set the useRepositoryLayout property without touching either the pom or my settings.xml?

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Answer was right in front of me in the copy-dependencies mojo docs (I even linked to it).  The documentation for the property includes the Expression you can refer to it by.

> useRepositoryLayout: Place each
>   artifact in the same directory layout
>   as a default repository. example:
>   /outputDirectory/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
>
> ```
> * Type: boolean
> * Since: 2.0-alpha-2
> * Required: No
> * Expression: ${mdep.useRepositoryLayout}
> * Default: false
> ```

To set this property from command line you need to run

```
mvn -Dmdep.useRepositoryLayout=true <goals go here>
```

Comment: To clarify, you need something like this: `mvn -Dmdep.useRepositoryLayout=true dependency:copy-dependencies`

Answer (score 16):

Define the properties as arbitrary properties ... not the standard maven props such as version.  In my case I defined a new property build.version:

```
<properties> build.version=unknown </properties>
```

I use the property:

```
<warName>${build.version}</warName>
```

I define the property:

```
mvn -P prod -Dbuild.version=app_name-branch_name-build_number package
```

Comment: Here is a good link: http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html#resource-filtering-sect-user-defined

Comment: Although the original user's specific question was answered, this response answers the generic question that was the title of the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Usually you set maven properties using the same syntax as java system properties. Have you tried the following line?

```
mvn -DuseRepositoryLayout=true dependency:copy-dependencies
```

Comment: This only works if the plugin author has annotated the variable with an expression. They will be shown in the plugin docs as shown in the above answer.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here were not clear to me. This is the way I understand it:

If the plugin code uses a system property for its parameter, then you can define the value on the command line.

There are 3 different ways you can accomplish this in the plugin code:

```
@parameter expression="${aSystemProperty}" 
@parameter default-value="${anExpression}"
@parameter property="aSystemProperty"
```

If any or a combination of these methods are used in the plugin code for a particular property, then you can specify a value for the plugin parameter, on the command line. Above code was taken from [maven docs here](https://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html).

If you are using a plugin with the above code, you could specify a value for your property using the following command:

```
mvn -DaSystemProperty=my-value <goal-here>
```