# How to download jars from Maven Central without writing any pom.xml

Tags: maven-2, java

I would like something like the following.

I want just an utility that is able to download jars and their dependencies from the Maven Repository without imposing no constraints on how my project should be built.

I would like something like this:

```
download-jar --dest=lib/ 'commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4'
```

It should be able to download also the dependencies.

**Update:**

I wouldn't know about a pom.xml should be structured.

The only task I need to be accomplished is the download of the jars, I would like have a tool that could accomplish this task that doesn't bother me with superflous information.

There is something like that?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, because the referenced question regards fetching deps to the local m2 repo, whereas this question specifies "without imposing no constraints" with an example showing a custom destination (lib/).

Comment: I totally agree. And the answer is: <code>mvn -Dartifact=commons-io:commons-io:1.4:jar -DoutputDirectory=$(pwd) -Dpackaging=jar dependency:copy</code>

Comment: Improved argument order: mvn dependency:copy -DoutputDirectory=$(pwd) -Dartifact=commons-io:commons-io:1.4:jar

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you want to download maven dependencies into your lib directory use the dependency plugin with the `copy-dependencies` function.

```
mvn -DoutputDirectory=./lib -DincludeArtifactIds=commons-logging,commons-io dependency:copy-dependencies
```

Without the `-DincludeArtifactIds` part you'll download every dependency.

If you want to download a an artifact without having a specific project *see below** :

```
mvn -DgroupId=commons-io -DartifactId=commons-io -Dversion=1.4 dependency:get
```

---

**Resources :**

- [maven.apache.org - dependency:copy-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html)
- [force Maven2 to copy dependencies into target/lib](http://www.weask.us/entry/force-maven2-copy-dependencies-target-lib)
- [maven.apache.org - dependency:get](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) *see below**

**On the same topic :**

- [Aggregate Dependencies in a Multi-Module Maven Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435130/aggregate-dependencies-in-a-multi-module-maven-project)
- [Set plugin's property on the command line in maven 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752724/set-plugins-property-on-the-command-line-in-maven-2)
- [A simple command line to download a remote maven2 artifact to the local repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776496/a-simple-command-line-to-download-a-remote-maven2-artifact-to-the-local-repositor) *see below**

**Interesting comments :**

- *@Pascal Thivent :

  > No need to setup a POM, no need to develop your own tool, use mvn dependency:get. That's the right answer to this question.

Comment: Thank you. This requires to have a proper pom.xml. This is the think I would avoid. Do you know a way to obtain the same result without defining the pom?

Comment: Making a proper maven pom.xml and using that to download your dependencies takes about a 5 minutes.  Setting up some other software and configuring it to scrape the library and parse POM.xmls for your dependencies and download those dependencies recursively will take quite a bit longer.

Comment: @Chris No need to setup a POM, no need to develop your own tool, use `mvn dependency:get`.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent, Nice one, `dependency:get` doesn't appear on the dependency's goals list.

Comment: @Colin You need version 2.1 of the dependency plugin. Follow [the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776496/a-simple-command-line-to-download-a-remote-maven2-artifact-to-the-local-repositor) of my comment to the question.

Comment: @Pascal Even quicker.  I learn something new here every day.

Comment: @Pascal Just to be clear, dependency:get installs to local m2 repo? According to **Eric B.** s answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776496/a-simple-command-line-to-download-a-remote-maven2-artifact-to-the-local-reposito), it has a **-Ddest** option, but since that specifies a filename then I assume we arene't resolving *its'* deps (i.e. we just fetch that one jar); Is this all correct?

Comment: Just a note, copy-dependencies requires a project/POM, and **-DincludeArtifactIds** will only get artifacts specified in the POM; Any others specified will be ignored (with no error message regarding this). Also, it appears that there may be an effect on transitive dependencies, as mentioned by **Matthias** [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973889/copy-dependencies-transitive-and-not-transitive).

Comment: `dependency:get` is great, but is there a way to download the artifacts into a particular directory, instead of into the local Maven repo?

Comment: `-DoutputDirectory=/path/to/output` @AvivCohn

Answer (score 20):

I also had to specify `-DrepoUrl`, after getting the error message:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get 
  (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The parameters 'repositoryUrl' 
  for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get are 
  missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
```

So here is the command I used:

```
mvn -DgroupId=edu.umd -DartifactId=cloud9 -Dversion=1.3.5 \
  -DrepoUrl="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2" dependency:get
```

Furthemore, `-Ddest=~` didn't work. It always insisted on installing the jar to `~/.m2/repository`.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  This was super helpful for me.  No `pom.xml` needed ;)

Comment: What is with the `\\` in the middle of the command? -_-

Comment: "\" allows copy-&-pasting the command into your terminal or shell script. Otherwise the newlines would trigger execution of each line individually. It could be one long line, but SO doesn't use `white-space: pre-wrap`, unfortunately, so too-long lines get cut off.

Answer (score 10):

**Maven3** uses dependency plugin v2.1 by default:

```
$ mvn dependency:get -DrepoUrl=http://download.java.net/maven/2/ \
   -DgroupId=commons-io -DartifactId=commons-io -Dversion=1.4
```

With **Maven2** is still necessary to write the canonical name:

```
$ mvn2 org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get \
   -DrepoUrl=http://download.java.net/maven/2/ \
   -DgroupId=commons-io -DartifactId=commons-io -Dversion=1.4
```

Use parameter `artifact` to set the name of the artifact as *group:artifact:version*:

```
$ mvn dependency:get -DrepoUrl=http://download.java.net/maven/2/ \
   -Dartifact=commons-io:commons-io:1.4
```

Use `LATEST` to download the latest version of the artifact:

```
$ mvn dependency:get -DrepoUrl=http://download.java.net/maven/2/ \
   -Dartifact=commons-io:commons-io:LATEST
```

Comment: What is with the `\\` in the middle of the command? -_-

Comment: @IulianOnofrei nothing related to 'mvn' :) Character '\' is used in bash to concatenate a command that is splitted into two or more lines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871332/how-to-tell-bash-that-the-line-continues-on-the-next-line

Comment: I see, I got annoyed it was not working until I realized I have to delete that, so that's a downside for unexperienced windows users though :(

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/), maybe ... and especially its [go-offline](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html) mojo

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/). It allows dependency resolution from maven repositories without the overkill complexity of maven itself.