# How to tell bash that the line continues on the next line

Tags: bash

In a bash script I got from another programmer, some lines exceeded 80 columns in length. What is the character or thing to be added to the line in order to indicate that the line continues on the next line?

Comment: See additional discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599711/how-can-i-split-a-shell-command-over-multiple-lines-when-using-an-if-statement

Answer (score 233, accepted):

The character is a backslash `\`

From the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

> The backslash character ‘\’ may be used to remove any special meaning
>   for the next character read and for line continuation.

Comment: thanks. and what is the usual limit in columns of a bash script?

Comment: bash has no interesting column limit; for clarity you should try to limit to 70-80 chars per column.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me? Is it contingent on other factors? bash version?

Comment: @RyanM The backslash has to be the very last character before the end of line character. Are you SURE you don't have any whitespace after the \ ?

Comment: @George Yeah. A little more fiddling spit out an error with a `^M`. The problem appears to be that the script was given to me by someone that uses windows. A quick `dos2unix` fixed it :)

Comment: @George your comment just saved me, I had a space after the \ and I couldn't figure out what was wrong. Cheers!

Comment: We could replace the link in the answer with https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read (I added an anchor to the specific section)

Answer (score 77):

In general, you can use a backslash at the end of a line in order for the command to continue on to the next line. However, there are cases where commands are implicitly continued, namely when the line ends with a token than cannot legally terminate a command. In that case, the shell knows that more is coming, and the backslash can be omitted. Some examples:

```
# In general
$ echo "foo" \
> "bar"
foo bar

# Pipes
$ echo foo |
> cat
foo

# && and ||
$ echo foo &&
> echo bar
foo
bar
$ false ||
> echo bar
bar
```

Different, but related, is the implicit continuation inside quotes. In this case, *without* a backslash, you are simply adding a newline to the string.

```
$ x="foo
> bar"
$ echo "$x"
foo
bar
```

*With* a backslash, you are again splitting the logical line into multiple logical lines.

```
$ x="foo\
> bar"
$ echo "$x"
foobar
```

Comment: Is there a formal list of such situations, where a command is implicitly continued onto the next line? It seems to me that I could leave the backslash out in certain circumstances within a `[[`-`]]` condition, but not in others, and I'm trying to figure out the rules.

Answer (score 32):

`\` does the job. @Guillaume's answer and @George's comment clearly answer this question. Here I explains why `The backslash has to be the very last character before the end of line character.` Consider this command:

```
   mysql -uroot \
   -hlocalhost
```

If there is a space after `\`, the line continuation will not work. The reason is that `\`  removes the special meaning for the next character which is a space not the invisible line feed character. The line feed character is after the space not `\` in this example.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the "very last character" part. I was getting a bit frustrated tracking exactly this bug.