# Spreading bash command over lines with \ error

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash scripts and know basic programming. I want to spread the command over several lines for readability but my script doesn't run on my Raspberry Pi. However if I copy to my Putty session it works fine. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo rrdtool create test.rrd  --step 5 \
DS:speed:GAUGE:60:-10:50 \
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:12
```

This is the error:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/test $ sudo bash ./makedb.sh
'RROR: can't parse argument '
./makedb.sh: line 3: DS:speed:GAUGE:60:-10:50: command not found
./makedb.sh: line 4: RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:12: command not found
```

Here's what it the file looks like it Notepad++ with show all characters on: https://i.imgur.com/kX7F7fK

I think it should be ok as there are no characters between the \ and newline as described here: [How can I split a command over multiple lines when using an IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599711/how-can-i-split-a-command-over-multiple-lines-when-using-an-if-statement)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Its probably not bash which is confused but sudo not knowing what to do with the line breaks

Comment: Your file has DOS line feeds. Run `dos2unix` on it or Google how to do it with `tr`. Maybe in the future don't use a Wintendo to edit your files.

Comment: Yes it was the line endings, however I used Notepad++ to convert the line endings: http://techtips-it.blogspot.com/2011/04/can-i-convert-file-format-in-notepad.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DS:speed:GAUGE:60:-10:50: command not found` this means that you're not escaping end of the line.

Use `cat -A` to see non-printable characters:

example:

```
head -3 /etc/passwd | cat -A 
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash$
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh$
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh$
```

See the end of line `$`

When you use `cat -A  makedb.sh` you should see:

```
sudo rrdtool create test.rrd  --step 5 \$
DS:speed:GAUGE:60:-10:50 \$
RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:12
```

If you have anything between `\` and `$` it will not work

Comment: 'cat -A  makedb.sh' gave me line endings '\^M$'. I fixed it by switching to unix line endings in Notepad++ as here:http://techtips-it.blogspot.com/2011/04/can-i-convert-file-format-in-notepad.html