# Unix Bash - Assign if/else to Variable

Tags: bash, unix

I have been creating to assign the output of if/else to a variable but keep on getting an error.

*For Example:*

```
mathstester=$(If [ 2 = 2 ]
Then echo equal
Else
echo "not equal"

fi)
```

So whenever I add `$mathstester` in a script, laid out like this:

```
echo "Equation: $mathstester"
```

It should display:

```
Equation: Equal
```

Do I need to lay it out differently? Is it even possible?

Comment: what are you trying to do? your if statement is missing a `fi`.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to add it here.

Comment: That's not the correct syntax for an `if`. This will work: `x = $(if [ 2 = 2 ]; then echo equal; else echo "not equal; fi)`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs . Note that case matters -- `If` and `if` are not the same.

Comment: if you want to echo it in one line. you need `echo -n text`.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Putting the `if` statement in the assignment is rather clumsy and easy to get wrong. The more standard way to do this is to put the assignment inside the `if`:

```
if [ 2 = 2 ]; then
    mathstester="equal"
else
    mathstester="not equal"
fi
```

As for testing variables, you can use something like `if [ "$b" = 2 ]` (which'll do a string comparison, so for example if b is "02" it will NOT be equal to "2") or `if [ "$b" -eq 2 ]`, which does numeric comparison (integers only). If you're actually using bash (not just a generic POSIX shell), you can also use `if [[ "$b" -eq 2 ]]` (similar to `[ ]`, but with somewhat cleaner syntax for more complicated expressions), and `(( b == 2 ))` (these do numeric expressions only, and have *very* different syntax). See [BashFAQ #31: What is the difference between test, [ and [[ ?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) for more details.

Answer (score 15):

The correct way to use `if` is:

```
mathtester=$(if [ 2 = 2 ]; then echo "equal"; else echo "not equal"; fi)
```

For using this in multiline statements you might consider looking [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599711/how-can-i-split-a-bash-command-over-multiple-lines-when-using-an-if-statement).

Comment: How about if I have a variable called $number which a 5, how would put that into the if statement?

Comment: How about reading the bash basics ? http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/