# Error: Unable to access jarfile - when running bfg.jar

Tags: java, git, macos, bfg-repo-cleaner

I am unable to run the bfg jar command over the git repo I am trying to clean.

Java version "1.8.0_201"
JDK version 1.8.0_201
MacOs Sierra 10.13.3

I downloaded BFG to /usr/local/bin
So total path is /usr/local/bin/bfg-1.11.6.jar

If I run:

java -jar /usr/local/bin/bfg-1.11.6.jar --delete-files  .git

I keep getting 'Error: Unable to access jarfile /usr/local/bin/bfg-1.11.6.jar'

I cannot believe this is the best way of doing a manual clean up of git?
Reading this -> one [Error: Unable to access jarfile bfg.jar - BFG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428981/error-unable-to-access-jarfile-bfg-jar-bfg) did not help.

Any thoughts?

Comment: could be a permissions problem, update the permissions of the jar or move to a public directory and try using it from there

Comment: Take a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943948/what-causes-unable-to-access-jar-file-error

May be it will be helpful

Comment: I tried moving it to my home dir and tried from there, no success. I then did a fresh install with homebrew and it made usr/local/bin/bfg . Then I run java -jar usr/local/bin/bfg --delete-files emailConfig.js git@github.com:project.git with no success, I get Error: Unable to access jarfile usr/local/bin/bfg. STUCK!

Comment: You are on MacOS - are you sure you checked this answer on the previously-linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46727738/452210 ?

Answer (score 0):

I had not installed the sbt console and ran bfg/assembly on the scala files; this is what actually gave me the jar executable in the end.

This urls helped me with this issue;

https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/issues/191