# stdin input to awk inside shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

On the bash shell I use the command

```
cat filename | cut -d, -f4 | sort -n | awk '
  BEGIN {
    c = 0;
    sum = 0;
  }
  $1 ~ /^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?$/ {
    a[c++] = $1;
    sum += $1;
  }
  END {
    ave = sum / c;
    if( (c % 2) == 1 ) {
      median = a[ int(c/2) ];
    } else {
      median = ( a[c/2] + a[c/2-1] ) / 2;
    }
    OFS="\t";
    print sum, c, ave, median, a[0], a[c-1];
  }
'
```

This works fine when run from terminal
But my shell script shows awk usage when trying to use the above commands inside a script and run the script.
I did

```
#!/bin/sh

diffFile="del.csv"



x=$(cat $diffFile | cut -d, -f4 | sort -n | awk 
  'BEGIN {
    c = 0;
    sum = 0;
  }
  $1 ~ /^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?$/ {
    a[c++] = $1;
    sum += $1;
  }
  END {
    ave = sum / c;
    if( (c % 2) == 1 ) {
      median = a[ int(c/2) ];
    } else {
      median = ( a[c/2] + a[c/2-1] ) / 2;
    }
    OFS="\t";
    print sum, c, ave, median, a[0], a[c-1];
  }'
)

echo "$x"
```

But this shows awk usage on running the script. How do I fix this.

Comment: You have a small difference in capitalization when using your filename variable. `diffFile` vs. `$diffFIle`.  I assume that's causing `cat` to wait for standard input, causing the freeze.

Comment: @jas thanks for pointing out. Now on running the script it shows awk usage :(

Comment: Well, that's some kind of progress at least :-).  Try starting your awk script on the same line as the command, or alternatively escape the newline with a backslash.

Comment: You need to escape the newline before the awk command, i.e. write `x=$(cat $diffFile | cut -d, -f4 | sort -n | awk  \ `. Otherwise, bash will think you try to invoke awk with no arguments.

Comment: put your variable in back tick like below - 

  " x=\`cat dict.txt | cut -d'|' -f4 | sort -n|awk '{print $0}'\`"

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR in general, backticks are strongly discouraged for `bash` due to easy syntax errors. the `$(...)` syntax does exactly the same and is more readable

Comment: Note the difference of where you put the initial single quote in the command line version that works. Do the same in the script version and you should be fine.

Comment: Can you please put the single quote with awk like below -

x=$(cat $diffFile | cut -d, -f4 | sort -n | awk '

Comment: @pythonRcpp - Add "\" at the end of awk in x variable line or try above solution.

Comment: Thanks guys, it works ! What should I do now. @aserre jas. should I delete the question now ?

Comment: There are several questions that could be duplicates for your question. [this one is the most upvoted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599711/how-can-i-split-a-shell-command-over-multiple-lines-when-using-an-if-statement), and [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82182/having-multi-lines-in-bash-command-substitution) is almost exactly similar but is on a different SE site