# run bash script over files that have not been converted

Tags: python, json, shell, csv

I have a python script to convert json files to csv. It currently converts all files, but I want it to run only on those json files that have not been  converted to csv already. All are in the same directory. How can I modify my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# file: foo.sh
for f in *.json; do
  python ~/bin/convert.py "$f" "-fcsv"
done
```

Comment: *that have not been converted to csv already* - and how do you expect this condition to be verified? Noone even saw your `convert.py` content

Comment: I was hoping for some bash conditional looping, of the sort: for f in *.json && !*.csv; do

Comment: Well obviously your convert.py file should rename the resulting file into .csv

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that OP is running this over a lot of large json files each of which takes a long time to convert. So he is trying to optimize run time, so that the `convert.py` runs only over those files that havent been converted. Is that correct?

IMO, its better to change the convert.py program, rather than write a bash wrapper on top of the `convert.py` (unless you are not allowed, or dont know how to change the `convert.py` program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your script creates `basename.csv` for an input file named `basename.json`

```
for f in *.json; do
    test -e "${f%.json}.csv" && continue
    python ~/bin/convert.py "$f" "-fcsv"
done
```

The shell parameter expansion `$(variable%pattern}` produces the value of `variable` with any match on the glob `pattern` removed.

Answer (score -1):

This leverages the `find` GNU-util and uses `python` for
the rest. Since you are running a python script, I am assuming that python is
installed on the system.

Full command below:

```
find . \( -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex  '.*json' \) - exec python -c "import sys; import os; filename, file_extension = os.path.splittext(sys.argv[1]); if not os.path.isfile(filename + '.csv') : os.system('python ~/bin/convert ' + filename + file_extension + ' -fcsv')" {}
```

#### searches for files with .json extension

```
find . \( -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex  '.*json' \)
```

#### takes the output from the find command and enters it into the python namespace

```
filename, file_extension = os.path.splittext(sys.argv[1]);
```

#### checks if there is a filename with extension .csv, if not runs the convert.py program

```
if not os.path.isfile(filename+'.csv'): os.system('python ~/bin/convert.py ' + filename+file_extension + ' -fcsv')"
```

You can put the entire script into a bash script and use `\` to break it up into multiple lines as shown here: [How can I split a shell command over multiple lines when using an IF statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599711/how-can-i-split-a-shell-command-over-multiple-lines-when-using-an-if-statement)

Comment: if the answer didnt answer the question, please leave a comment as to why it didn't fit OP's question